# Contact Form 7 Plugin Notification Position

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I`am trying to setup a contact form for my contact page . Everything is ok except the notifications of Contact Form. The Messages are not visible , when the message was sent successfully or when their is an error. Iam posting a screenshot to show you where the notification position appears.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the style of that box to make sure the copy isn't just the same color as the background?

Comment: yesi checked the message box color depends if its successful would be green and on error red

Comment: Not the message box color, the text color in the box. Is it the same as the message box? If you look at the page source is there copy in the box?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/cngvd6 i moved it through developer tools take a look

Comment: maybe i will manually get the notification box class for error and success and move it manual to the center

Comment: Do you have a link I can test?